# How to investigate what's in heap/stack of Java Virtual Machine of Google App Engine instances

Tags: java, google-app-engine

is there any way to investigate what is contained in the heap/stack of 
Java Virtual Machine of Google App Engine instances ?

In Google App Engine Dashboard we see ourinstances with high 
Memory usages.

For example visiting https://appengine.google.com/instances we see ...

```
Module: default Version: v5372 (Default)

App         Total number            Average     Average     Average
Engine      number                  QPS*        Latency*    Memory
Release     of instances                        

1.8.5       6 total (1 Resident)    0.008       1521.3 ms   174.6 MBytes

Instances   

QPS*    Latency*    Requests    Errors  Age         Memory          App Engine Release  Availability
0.000   0.0 ms      119         0       2:37:30     222.6 MBytes   1.8.5               Resident
0.050   1521.3 ms   911         0       1:37:12     250.4 MBytes   1.8.5               Dynamic
0.000   0.0 ms      2           0       0:01:52     132.4 MBytes   1.8.5               Dynamic
0.000   0.0 ms      51          0       2:47:17     186.8 MBytes   1.8.5               Dynamic
0.000   0.0 ms      2           0       2:46:57     88.1 MBytes    1.8.5               Dynamic
0.000   0.0 ms      29          0       2:48:05     167.5 MBytes   1.8.5               Dynamic
```

... cannot figure out what is being stored in 200 MBytes ?!?

... on the server side we use Guice for injection with all server side classes
annotated as @RequestScoped (... should be released as far ad the request is
handled), except the ObjectifyFactory which is annotated as @Singleton (... 
this only one should remain in the JVM Heap).

Thanks in advance
Tino